# How does one get all files in a directory with a specific pattern in their names in Python

Tags: python, glob, listdir

I need to get all filenames from a directory with a specific ending. The files i want from the directory have the same name but with different numbers, other files exist in the same directory. All the files are numbered in the following format:

```
Project_Name_1.txt
Project_Name_2.txt
Project_Name_3.txt
Project_Name_14.txt
Project_Name_19.txt
Project_Name_31.txt
```

The number of files can vary. And The file names (apart from the numbering) are user dependent. 
I'm looking for something like the following:

```
[s for s in os.listdir(directory) if "*_*.txt" in s ]
```

or

```
glob.glob(directory, '*_?.txt')
```

Comment: Do you want to get filenames according to user's name (the "project_Name_" part) too, or just according to the ending (.txt, .pdf, etc) ?

Comment: @eyquem The "project_Name_" part can change depending on the user, so the first option please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
name = 'Project_Name'
glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '{}_*.txt'.format(name)))
```

this lets files like "Project_Name_SOMETHING.txt" through, so you want to check them afterwards.

Comment: I wonder: is there any advantage to write ``'{}_*.txt'.format(name)`` instead of ``%s_*.txt' % name`` ?

Comment: @eyquem - "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code."

Comment: @eumiro I know this recommendation, but I find use of %s more readable for simple cases. However, if there would be an advantage of format() upon %s even for simple cases, I would use format().